# Add Subview to SKStoreProductViewController

Tags: ios, uiwindow

I am trying to counteract Apple's lack of innovation with SKStoreProductViewController.  Im pretty certain this isn't possible, but lets see.

I am presenting the view controller outside of this block:

```
    [storeController loadProductWithParameters:productParameters completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {}];
    [self presentViewController:storeController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

That way the view controller shows immediately, rather than waiting 30 seconds to load the product.  However, now it obviously shows a blank controller while it loads the product.  I would love to put a `UIActivityIndicatorView`on the window until the product loads.  I have tried this:

```
      [self presentViewController:storeController animated:YES completion:^{
            UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
            [activity startAnimating];
            activity.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);
            activity.center = self.view.window.center;
            [self.view.window addSubview:activity];
        }];
```

No luck there.  Is it possible to add an activity indicator on top of this view?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to bring up the view controller once the SKStoreProductViewController loading is completed? like this

```
[storeController loadProductWithParameters:productParameters completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) 
{
    [self presentViewController:storeController animated:YES completion:^{}];
}];
```

Comment: I have, but this causes quite the delay for the user.  They press the button...then depending on network conditions, nothing happens and eventually the store kit fires.  Unfortunately it doesn't work great with the UI to throw an activity indicator before the view fires.

Comment: out of curiosity, does that mean loadProduct on SKStoreProductViewController takes too long?

Comment: Ya and since it is waiting for completion in this case the view controller doesn't show.  'Too Long' is of course relative, but on let 30 seconds sometimes...thats too long for me with no user feedback.

Comment: not aware of your code, is it possible for SKStoreProductViewController to call -loadProductWithParameters much earlier? So that when its time to present the new view controller, you can switch instantly?

Comment: Kind of...thats the direction I'm leaning, I display many possible products on one page so assume the one the user is going to press is sometimes difficult, but that is the direction I'm going

Comment: good luck. Don't forget to post your solution on here if you find one